# Create React App 2 - remove html attribute for testing

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

Is it possible to connect Create React App 2 with this plugin:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-jsx-remove-data-test-id without ejecting?
I've created `.bablerc` file, but it doesn't work.
I want to use custom attribute for bdd testing and remove this attribute on production.

Also, I don't want to create HOC to apply attribute - I have many components and wrap every component is very very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-app-rewired` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired and override the configs through the config-override.js file:

```
const {
  override,
  addBabelPresets,
  addBabelPlugins,
} = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  ...addBabelPresets([
    '@babel/preset-env',
    {
      modules: false,
      useBuiltIns: false,
      debug: false,
    },
  ]),
  ...addBabelPlugins(
    'babel-plugin-styled-components',
    'babel-plugin-jsx-remove-data-test-id',
  ),
);
```